# Generally multithreading a for loop in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, performance, loops

Suppose I am given integers `a` and `b` such that a range of interest is formed, of integers in `[a,b]`. The range can span well over `10^9` integers. I want to sum the values of a given function `f : N -> N` over all integers `a <= n <= b`. The range is very large so I want to do this using multithreading.

Less formaly, I want to parallelize the following code:

```
long sum = 0;
    
for (long n = a ; n <= b ; n++)
    sum += f(n);
    
System.out.println(sum);
```

Ideally (at least in my mind), the range will divided equally across the available number of threads available by the processor (suppose `f(n)` has near-identical complexity and running time for each `n` in range). The values are completely independent, and `f` could really be any function. For example, it could output the sum of digits of the number, but it really could be anything, it's just an example.

Is there a general way to do exactly that in Java using multithreading?

Comment: Use `RecursiveTask`, which is appropriate for such a problem. It is based on the `ForkJoinPool` threading, which will create all necessary thread for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This particular use-case fits very well for a parallel stream. See [tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html). Use [`java.util.stream.LongStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/LongStream.html) class for a stream of 64-bit `long` integers.

You can implement it like this:

```java
long sum = LongStream.rangeClosed(a, b)
    .parallel()
    .map(n -> f(n))
    .sum();

System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Excellent, it's what I was looking for. Is there a simple modification to obtain a "mod-ed" result? I.E, `sum % mod`. Assuming intermediate sums exceed `mod` and exceed 64-bit long range, so some "mods" need to be performed along the way. I can sum `f(n) % mod` but it won't be enough, because the total sum can still exceed 64-bit range using just this.

Comment: @Matan You can probably use the `reduce`-function for that. It's a more general function than `sum`. The equivalent to `sum` using `reduce` would be `.reduce((currSum, value) -> currSum + value)`. You can modify that to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look into the [fork/join framework](https://www.baeldung.com/java-fork-join); it's a generalized approach to this principle of splitting up a task into a great many little independent tasks and then combining them back together, and gives you all control you'd want about how to spin off threads.

Alternatively, you can use the `parallel()` method of the stream API, but note that this method doesn't explain or guarantee much about how it works. You have no control over which aspect is parallelized, and no control over the amount of threads that'll be involved. For trivial cases you might as well use it, but as a rule, if 'uhoh I better write this in parallel or it would be too slow' is relevant, then you need some guarantees and some control. Here's [oracle's tutorial/explanation on parallel streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html). For this specific case it does seem like it would more or less do what you want (it gets tricky if e.g. the stream you attempt to apply this to is e.g. what `Files.lines` gives you - where the parallelism gets potentially stymied by where it is applied vs. where the bottleneck is).

Comment: He doesn't want the sum of all integers between a and b though. He is applying the function `f` to every element as well.

Comment: Good point. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`RecursiveTask` is suitable for such a problem. Threads will be managed by the `ForkJoinPool`.

The general idea is to decompose the problem into shorter sub-problems, up to the point a single thread is able to manage the given sub-problem by itself.

```
class RecursiveSum extends RecursiveTask<Long> {
    private final int THLD = 1_000;
    private int low, high;
    public RecursiveSum(int high) {
        this(0,high);
    }
    public RecursiveSum(int low, int high) {
        this.low = low; this.high = high;
    }
    
    private long sum(int l,int h) {
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i=l; i<h; i++) sum += i;
        return sum;
    }

    @Override
    protected Long compute() {
        int len = high-low;
        if (len<=THLD) return sum(low,high);
        RecursiveSum rhalf = new RecursiveSum(low+len/2,high);
        rhalf.fork();
        RecursiveSum lhalf = new RecursiveSum(low,low+len/2);
        high = low+len/2;
        return lhalf.compute()+rhalf.join();
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
long r = new RecursiveSum(1_000_000_000).invoke();
System.out.println("Sum="+r);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. create your sum class (edit 'f' function to your function):

   ```
   class sumFun implements Callable<Long> {
      public long f(long num){
         return num;
      }
      private long a;
      private long b;
      public sumFun(long a, long b) {
          this.a = a;
          this.b = b;
      }
      @Override
      public Long call() {
          long sum = 0;
          for (long i = a; i <= b; i++) {
              sum += f(i);
          }
          return sum;
      }
   }
   ```
2. in main :

   ```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
       long start = 1;
       long end = 10000000;
       int numOfThreads = 5;
       long step = (end - start + 1) / numOfThreads;
       List<sumFun> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
       for (long i = start; i <= end; i += step) {
           long tmp = end;
           if(i+step-1 < end){
               tmp = i+step-1;
           }
           tasks.add(new sumFun(i, tmp));
       }
       ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numOfThreads);
       List<Future<Long>> results = executor.invokeAll(tasks);
       long sum = 0;
       for (Future<Long> result : results) {
           sum += result.get();
       }
       System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
       executor.shutdown();
    }
   ```